# Slideshow control for use in Wordpress Thesis theme - non flash

Tags: plugin-recommendation, slideshow, theme-thesis

I want to use a good elegant slideshow control in my website. The website is created in wordpress and I am using the Thesis theme.

I did find a Nivo slider but am stuck at the integration with Thesis (using the custom functions and custom css files).

Can someone suggest a good non-flash slideshow widget which I can easily integrate with the theme (and also how to integrate it)

Thanks.

Comment: I have reopened your question and bumped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list with some of the widgets: http://www.geeksucks.com/showcases/12-awesome-wordpress-slideshow-plugins.htm

Then, here is the slideshow list from the official plugin directory: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/slideshow

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But still could not find something with steps to integrate with the Thesis theme.

Comment: Used a custom home page template and integrated one of the slideshow controls from this URL. Thanks Alex